# Party schedule - classical knapsack

Tags: c++, algorithm, knapsack-problem

The input is a available budget, number of parties, the ticket-price of each party and the amount of fun on the party. The task is to output the maximum possible fun with available budget and the budget used. If you can choose between two parties with the same fun, choose the cheaper one. (It is a [SPOJ problem](http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/PARTY/).)

I created two arrays:

- `m[i][j]` is the maximum fun to get from all parties up to i with
  budget j
- `p[i][j]` minimum price to py to get max. fun from parties
  up to i with budget j

Then, for each i up to #parties and for each j up to budget I calculated the value of `m[i][j]` and `p[i][j]` like this:

```
for(T i = 1; i <= parties; i++) {
    for(T j = 0; j <= budget; j++) {
        //We get more fun by attending party i
        if(price[i] <= j && m[i-1][j-price[i]] + fun[i] > m[i-1][j]) {
            m[i][j] = m[i-1][j-price[i]] + fun[i];
            p[i][j] = p[i-1][j-price[i]] + price[i];
        //We get same fun by attending i, but more cheaply
        } else if(price[i] <= j && m[i-1][j-price[i]] + fun[i] == m[i-1][j] && p[i-1][j-price[i]] + price[i] < p[i-1][j]) {
            m[i][j] = m[i-1][j-price[i]] + fun[i];
            p[i][j] = p[i-1][j-price[i]] + price[i];
        //We can't visit the party
        } else {
            m[i][j] = m[i-1][j];
            p[i][j] = p[i-1][j];
        }
    }
}
```

For any test case I found (I may share some if needed), this algorithm outputs the same answer as the algorithms approved by the online judge. However, this one is not approved.

What is wrong with the algorithm?

[Here](http://tny.cz/ab2b54b1) is the complete program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your complete code without going through your logic, but there were some must-be-wrong points:

1. You decalred your `price` array inside function as `price[parties]`, which only allows `price[0..parties - 1]`, but you used up to `price[parties]`, same as `fun[]`;
2. The condition for your `while` is `while(scanf("%u %u",&budget,&parties), budget != 0 && parties != 0)`, however `budget` can be `0` even in a valid input, so your program may terminate earlier than expected;
3. You declared your `m[][]` and `p[][]` inside function but didn't initialize it, so it would be filled up with rubbish values;
4. You print the answer using `printf("%u %u")`, but the problem requires a new line for each output, so here should be `printf("%u %u\n")`.

After I changed these 4 "bugs" in your program, it gets accepted :) So your algorithm logic is approved, but some "irrelevant" things prevents you from getting accepted. **Don't look down on these "details", they DO count!**